# MongoDB: Update fields in nested elements of the same document

Tags: mongodb

I have found plenty of posts about updating documents in MongoDB (3.4) using `$elemMatch`, `$set`, `$in`, etc. But what I need is to update all `animal_rules` when `type` is `any_rule2` in this nested *single document*.

```
{
    "_id": "id_1",
    "animals": {
        "a_random_very_long_id1": {
            "animal_actions": [{
                "type": "any_action1",
                "additional_things": [
                    "90000201"
                ]
            }],
            "animal_rules": [{
                "type": "any_rule1",
                "unrelated_field": 15
            }, {
                "type": "any_rule2",
                "important_value": 60
            }],
            "_id": "a_random_very_long_id1"
        },
        "a_random_very_long_id2": {
            "animal_actions": [{
                "type": "any_action2",
                "additional_things": [
                    "10567808"
                ]
            }],
            "animal_rules": [{
                    "type": "any_rule2",
                    "important_value": 50
                },
                {
                    "type": "any_rule3",
                    "other_unrelated_field": {
                        "type": "xx"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "_id": "a_random_very_long_id2"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried things like `db.general.find({'animals.$.animal_rules' : { $elemMatch : {"type":"any_rule2"}}})` but I can't even fetch results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any one-liner to fulfill this task, finally I came up with this Javascript function:

```
var x = db.general.findOne({"_id" : "_id1"});
for (key in x.animals) {
    rules = x.animals[key].animal_rules;
    rules.forEach(function (rule) {
        type = rule.type;
        if (type === 'any_rule2') {
            theValue = rule.important_value;
            rule.from = NumberInt(theValue);
            rule.to = NumberInt(theValue);
            delete rule.important_value;
        }
    });
printjson(x);
db.general.save(x);
}
```

Hope it serves someone :)